# Replacing data in files with new inputs

Tags: python, list, file

First of all my program must work with several files and 10 inputs in every file, this is just little piece, to be clear.

*My code right now:*

```
code = input(">> ")
print("\nPress <Enter> and parameter will be same!")

f = open("komad_namestaja.txt", "r")
allDATA = f.readlines()
f.close()
for line in allDATA:
    lst = line.split("|")

    if code == lst[0]:

        print("\nName :", lst[1])
        name = input("New Name >> ")
        if name == "":
            name = lst[1]

        f = open("komad_namestaja.txt", "r")
        allDATA = f.read()
        f.close()
        newdata = allDATA.replace(lst[1], name)
        f = open("komad_namestaja.txt", "w")
        f.write(newdata)
        f.close()

        print("\ndestination :", lst[2])
        destination = input("New destination >> ")
        if destination == "":
            destination = lst[2]

        #Writting function here
```

*File before:*

```
312|chessburger|Denmark
621|chesscake|USA
```

**code input:** 312

**name input:** Gyros

**destination input:** Poland

*file after inputs:*

```
312|Gyros|Poland
621|chesscake|USA
```

Problem is this replacing in file I cant write 7 lines code every time, because I have `10 x 5` inputs, and also I tried everything and cant make function of this.

I must write some function for reading/writing/replacing or replacing all inputs after last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to read the file in every time to modify one field, write it out, reopen it to change another field, and so on. That's inefficient, and in your case, causes code explosion.

Since your files are small, you could just read everything into memory at once and work on it in memory. Your code is easy to map via a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Here's a function that takes a filename and converts your file into a dictionary.

```
def create_mapping(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        data = infile.readlines()
        mapping = {int(k): (i,d) for k,i,d in 
                   (x.strip().split('|') for x in data)}
    # Your mapping now looks like
    # { 312: ('cheeseburger', 'Denmark'),
    #   621: ('chesscake', 'USA') }
    return mapping
```

Then you can update the mapping from user input since it's just a dictionary.

Once you want to write the file out, you can just serialize out your dictionary by iterating over the keys and rejoining all the elements using `|`.

#### If you want to use `list`s

If you want to stick with just using `list`s for everything, that is possible.

I would still recommend reading your file into a list, like so:

```
def load_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        data = infile.readlines()
        items = [(int(k), i, d) for k,i,d in
                 (x.strip().split('|') for x in data]
        # Your list now looks like
        # [(312, 'cheeseburger', 'Denmark'), (621, 'chesscake', 'USA')]
    return items
```

Then when you get some user input, you have to traverse the list and find the tuple with what you want inside.

For example, say the user entered `code 312`, you could find the tuple that contained the `312` value from the list of tuples with this:

```
items = load_file(filename)

# Get input for 'code' from user
code = int(input(">> "))

# Get the position in the list where the item with this code is
try: 
    list_position = [item[0] for item in items].index(code)
    # Do whatever you need to (ask for more input?)
    # If you have to overwrite the element, just reassign its
    # position in the list with
    # items[list_position] = (code, blah, blah)
except IndexError:
    # This means that the user's entered code wasn't entered
    # Here you do what you need to (maybe add a new item to the list),
    # but I'm just going to pass
    pass
```

Comment: @XpreSS If you need help I can provide more - I didn't want to basically rewrite your code for you and wanted to nudge you in the right direction. However, if you're going to be programming in python a lot, you should embrace using all the functionality like `dict`s. Some tutorials/quick documentation like [this one](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-python) may help.

Comment: actually i started this project with lists so i want to finish it just like i started.

Comment: Thanks for advise and Dict tut very much, i'll accept it.

Comment: @XpreSS - is that a requirement? If it is, it's also possible to read your files directly into a list of items. It would take more code to process items (mostly because they would probably be stored as `tuple` items and we'd have to remove things from lists and such), but it can be done. Let me know if you would like me to update my example to do list-based processing.

Comment: Sure i would like, i'm thinking to rewrite code where i used lists to dict, but that's not good idea.

Comment: @XpreSS - I added some stuff that should allow you to work solely with lists.